# check if program from list of programs is installed

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

Running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7.12.
I'd like to check, if list of programs are installed on machine.
So far, I have this not working piece of code:

```
import subprocess

program = ['rsync', 'locate']
  for x in program:
   cmd = "dpkg-query -W " + x + " | grep -c " + x
   process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, error = process.communicate()
```

I can run this command, if I'm not using program as string variable:

```
exists = subprocess.call("dpkg-query -W rsync | grep -c 'rsync'", shell=True)
```

and it returns 0/1. Can you help me how to build loop that returns if program is installed or not ? Possibly in 5 or so lines, all I need is simple True/False (0/1). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use **command -v**

```
 import subprocess

 list_cmd = ['rsync', 'locate', 'celery']

 for cmd in list_cmd:
     exist = subprocess.call('command -v '+ cmd + '>> /dev/null', shell=True)
     if exist == 0:
         print "I've got " + cmd
```

Your cmds (in list) must be executable in shell for use this solution.

Comment: yep, that works perfectly, thanks ! I only had to change print command syntax for Python 2.7 (print "I've got " + cmd)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using pythons `apt` [library](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html). They have all features available you currently seem need. I have no time currently to provide a sample - if necessary i'll do that later.

Comment: yes, i was using apt before, but I find it bit too slow, it takes couple of seconds to get apt.cache. Therefore I want to avoid using apt module. And one more thing, apt module is not installed by default, at least not in Ubuntu, so I'd have to install it before using it. I wand to do it as simple and quick as possible. Thanks for suggestion though